# Please help me get the hashed password

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get the hashed password for the admin.

I've tried to hash the password but I'm failing to insert it into the user object.

```
import encryptor from '../helpers/password';

let hashed_pswd = 'john123';
const hashPassword= async () => {
    const adminPwd = await encryptor.encryptPassword(hashed_pswd, 10);
    console.log(adminPwd);
}
hashPassword();

export default [
    {
        id: 1,
        first_name: 'john',
        last_name: 'doe',
        email: 'john@gmail.com',
        password: adminPwd,
        address: 'kigali',
        is_admin: true
    }
]
```

I'm being able to log the hashed password in the console but when I try to send a POST request, I'm getting that the *adminPwd* is not defined.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not a Javascript person, but I'd *guess* that the scope of `adminPwd` is the `hashPassword` function instead. I'd expect you to return the hashed password from the method. (I'd also change the name of the `hashed_pswd` variable, as that's *not* hashed - that's the plain text.)

Comment: Hi John, even when I return the **adminPwd**, I get the same error. I'm really able to return a hashed string in the console when I comment out the password: adminPwd inside  the object.

Comment: I think another problem is that hashPassword() is async but you aren't waiting for it. So it tries to populate the value even before the function has finished. Also inside there you call a method called encryptPassword...you realise the hashing and encryption are not the same thing??

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using `async/await` for the `hashPassword` function you may as well wrap your whole code in one and remove that function. You should rename your `hashed_pswd` variable to something more meaningful because it's not hashed at that stage. I've called it `password`.

```
import encryptor from '../helpers/password';

export default async () => {

  const password = 'john123';
  const hashedPassword = await encryptor.encryptPassword(password, 10);

  return [{
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'john',
    last_name: 'doe',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    password: hashedPassword,
    address: 'kigali',
    is_admin: true
  }];

};
```

And to `import` that module you'd have to use `async` to wrap your code because you're returning a promise from that `async` in `getUserData`.

```
import getUserData from './getUserData.mjs';

(async () => {

  console.log(await getUserData());

})();
```

Comment: the problem is that when I try to move the array inside a function, I get this error: ``` 'export ' or 'import' may be at the top level```.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. Let me work on it. It may be salvageable yet.

Comment: @Mo1, I don't know if this edit will help, but let me know if it does. I have tested it and it works, but it might not be suitable for you.

Answer (score -1):

In order to solve this you need to declare *adminPwd* using ***`let`*** instead of ***`const`*** in **global scope or in scope  where your export default section can access it**.

`Refer to modified code snippet:`

```
import encryptor from '../helpers/password';

let hashed_pswd = 'john123';
let adminPwd;
const hashPassword = async () => {
    adminPwd = await encryptor.encryptPassword(hashed_pswd, 10);
            console.log(adminPwd);
            return [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    first_name: 'john',
                    last_name: 'doe',
                    email: 'john@gmail.com',
                    password: adminPwd,
                    address: 'kigali',
                    is_admin: true
                }
            ]
}

export default hashPassword;
```

Wherever you were importing this, call exported function before using it.

`In order to Consume this response you have two options:`

1. In a async function using await keyword
2. If not consuming within async function use .then method of promise.

Comment: I tried that but I can't get the hashed password in the response body.

Comment: Please refer to modified solution.